# ObservableCollection edits are not saving

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, observablecollection

I have my ObservableCollection finally pulling data but now it's not saving the edits.

Here is my code:

```
public void FillDataGrid(Guid corporationId)
{
    var query = from s in entity.Sources
                where s.CorporationId == corporationId
                select new SourceItem
                {
                    CorporationId = s.CorporationId,
                    Description = s.Description,
                    IsActive = s.IsActive,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    SourceId = s.SourceId,
                    TokenId = s.TokenId
                };

    SoureItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<SourceItem>(query);
    SourceDataGrid.ItemsSource = SoureItemCollection;
    SourceDataGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    SourceDataGrid.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;
    SourceDataGrid.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

This is the class I am binding to:

```
public class SourceItem
{
    private Guid _corporationId1;
    private string _description;
    private bool _isActive;
    private string _name;
    private Guid _sourceId;
    private Guid _tokenId;

    public Guid CorporationId
    {
        set
        {
            _corporationId1 = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "CorporationId");
        }
        get { return _corporationId1; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "Description");
        }
        get { return _description; }
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        set
        {
            _isActive = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "IsActive");
        }
        get { return _isActive; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "NAme");
        }
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public Guid SourceId
    {
        set
        {
            _sourceId = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "SourceId");
        }
        get { return _sourceId; }
    }

    public Guid TokenId
    {
        set
        {
            _tokenId = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "TokenId");
        }
        get { return _tokenId; }
    }

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // OnPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the save:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Am I suppose to tie the ObservableCollection back to the entity before saving? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You've created a copy of the data and you're editing that copy. The entity framework context is completely unaware of this.

Instead of using fields in `SourceItem`, you can use the entity data object. For example:

```
var query = from s in entity.Sources
            where s.CorporationId == corporationId
            select new SourceItem(s);

class SourceItem
{
  private SourceEntity _model;

  public SourceItem(SourceEntity model)
  {
      _model = model;
  }

  public Guid CorporationId
  {
    get { return _mode.CorporationId; }
    set
    {
      _model.CorporationId = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(this, "CorporationId");
    }
  }
}
```

Note this has nothing to do with the `ObservableCollection`. If you're adding or deleting items from the collection, you'll also need to sync that to the entity model. You can use the `CollectionChanged` event for that.

Comment: I had the binding working with just saving records that already existed. This point of the ObservableCollection was to get the adding and deleting working...

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but I'm having problems with the `SourceItem`. I'm not sure what exactly that is suppose to be? `_model` isn't extended to the underlying fields as you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

see the problem is that with the expression "var query = from s in entity.Sources .. *select new SourceItem{..}*" you have not retrieved entities that are attached to context (entity) but you have created new objects of type SourceItem which can not be mapped back to db entities.
What you should do is that you should probably change your SourceItem class that it is directly backed by entity.Sources object (it should be it's constructor parameter I guess). Delegate SourceItem fields back to corresponding Sources fields (two way). So the SourceItem will encapsulate Sources object and decorate it with all the WPF stuff for MVVM manipulation.